# Best practices: mirroring model onto remote storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to implement transparent mirroring for some models I use in my Rails app. This implies calling remote API on model `create/update/delete`.

My approach is to rewrite respective methods of models this way and use ApiHelper to call remote api (see code for `project.rb` model):

```
include ApiHelper
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
   has_many :folders
   attr_accessible :name

   def create
     super
     ApiHelper.call 'Model.Create', {:name=>self.name}
   end
end
```

Is there another 'Rails way' to do that?

Comment: Is ActiveResource an alternative for you to use?
 - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html

Comment: That would work great in general. However, in my case, the API is not fully 'Restful' i think. It looks like: www.api.com?method=Model.Create&modelName=abc&sessionid=XYZ321... I also need to store a 'local' copy of model.